# Customize the Font Face, Font Color and Font size options for a RTF in CMS ribbon

Tags: 2013-sp1, rtf

Can we edit the options listing in the dropdown menu for Font Face, Font size and Font colour which appears once we click inside a RTF.
1). Can we add our own Font face for example "Test Font" along with other options as "Arial, Arial black, Test Font,.... and so on in drop down.
2). Can we replace our custom size parameter instead of 8pt, 9pt,.. with "small", "medium",... and so on.
3). Can we add our custom name for different font colours like:
 
    White - test-white
    Red - test-Red and so on.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, you can add your own fonts. See "[Configuring system fonts](http://docs.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL%20Tridion%20full%20documentation-v1/GUID-B92ABEEE-5932-4431-833D-F9291A1F3144)" in the documentation.

While you cannot replace the existing size options, you can add your own CSS classes - which then gives you full freedom of how you want to present the content. See the "[Styles configuration](http://docs.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL%20Tridion%20full%20documentation-v1/GUID-D95860F7-15DF-4091-B24E-3539F7CB33C4)" documentation page - and while you are there you might want to browse the related pages in that section :)

Comment: Thank you Peter for redirecting me to correct documents. :)